# How to fetch MIDI input-data in C++?

Tags: c++, input, midi

I've already googled the **** out of the web in search of a simple way to get data from a connected midi device. I'm using I Visual Studio 2010 on a Win7 64bit PC.

I've already tried libaries like [Improv](http://improv.sapp.org/), [JDKSmidi](https://github.com/jdkoftinoff/jdksmidi/tree/master/examples), [Portmidi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/wiki/Installing%20portmidi%20on%20Windows)
All their example programs compiled with errors and Portmidi did not really provide a useful documentation.

All I want to do, is to read midi input on windows in my program. (Maybe even without an extern libary?)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at rtmidi. It is small (2 headers and one .cpp file) and very easy to use.
http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/

Comment: Tried id. It's compiling but it keeps saysing "MidiInDummy: This class provides no functionality. There are 0 MIDI input sources available." I tried different midi devices with this. It's not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1511417 You're not compiling it correctly. You need to do a #define for whatever platform you're on. For example, on Windows compile with `__WINDOWS_MM__` defined. It's explained on the rtmidi website.

Comment: Here is a step by step guide for visual studio: http://beatinginfinity.blogspot.com/2013/05/use-rtmidi-in-windows-in-microsoft.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows, you may use Windows multimedia API.

It's quite simple.

[MSDN MIDI Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are several articles on codeproject :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2771/Wrapper-Library-for-Windows-MIDI-API

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36313/MIDI-Star